# make HTML table as a slideshow/carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, carousel

I have a html table,which i am populating using java script. the table has 10 cells.i want to make the table as a carousel so that first 5 cells are shown and then user can move to next 5 cells. I have tried looking on the internet,but all my search leads to plugins. i dont wana use plugin,as i am learning javascript.

My table code is shown below:
`<div>
                <table id="daily_forecast">
                    <tr id="time">
                        <td id="time0">
                        <td id="time1">
                        <td id="time2">
                        <td id="time3">
                        <td id="time4">
                        <td id="time5">
                        <td id="time6">
                        <td id="time7">
                        <td id="time8">
                        <td id="time9">
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="temp">
                        <td id="temp0">
                        <td id="temp1">
                        <td id="temp2">
                        <td id="temp3">
                        <td id="temp4">
                        <td id="temp5">
                        <td id="temp6">
                        <td id="temp7">
                        <td id="temp8">
                        <td id="temp9">
                    </tr>
                </table>`

and javascript wjich populates is

```
function populateTable(disp_forecast){
        var tbl=document.getElementById("daily_forecast");
                tbl.style.width  = '900px';
                tbl.style.height='200px';
                tbl.style.position="relative";
                tbl.style.left='60px';
                tbl.style.top='40px';

                tbl.style.border = '1px solid grey';

                elemrow1Id="time";
                elemrow2id="temp";
                elemrow1Id_day="day"
                var key4,key5,key6="";
                for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

                    key4=elemrow1Id.concat(i);
                    key5=elemrow2id.concat(i);
                    key6=elemrow1Id_day.concat(i);
                    var day_time=disp_forecast[key4];
                    var day_temp=disp_forecast[key5];
                    if(day_time==0){
                        var day=disp_forecast[key6];
                        day=day.toString();
                        day=day.concat('\n');
                        day=day.concat("12am");
                        document.getElementById(key4).innerHTML=day;
                        //document.getElementById(key5).innerHTML=day_temp;
                    }
                    else if(day_time>12){
                        day_time=day_time-12;
                        day_time=day_time.toString();
                        day_time=day_time.concat("pm");
                        document.getElementById(key4).innerHTML=day_time;
                        //document.getElementById(key5).innerHTML=day_temp;

                    }
                    else if(day_time==12){
                        day_time=day_time.toString();
                        day_time=day_time.concat("pm");
                        document.getElementById(key4).innerHTML=day_time;
                        //document.getElementById(key5).innerHTML=day_temp;
                    }
                    else{
                        day_time=day_time.toString();
                        day_time=day_time.concat("am");
                        document.getElementById(key4).innerHTML=day_time;
                        //document.getElementById(key5).innerHTML=day_temp;
                    }
                    document.getElementById(key5).innerHTML=day_temp;
                }
        }
```

Please provide me some resource for making this table as a carousel or some solution.

Comment: Don't use html tables for anything other than tabular data.

Comment: why table data man? use div ul li

Answer (score 0):

This might at least get you started (I'm assuming horizontal movement). Typically a carousel is a div inside a div, with the outer div acting as a viewport/window, revealing only the desired parts of the inner div. You then scoot the inner div in response to some buttons or key presses.

CSS

```
.outerWrap, .innerWrap {
    position: relative;
}

.outerWrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outerWrap">
    <div class="innerWrap">
        <table> <!-- your stuff goes here --> </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagNames('innerWrap')[0];
elem.style.left = "15px";
```

elem.style.left = "15px" is just an example of shifting the inner div to the right a little. You'll want to create a loop or something that moves it incrementally, probably in response to buttons, event listeners, etc...

Comment: BTA I've made a simple / raw carousel here: http://devjustice.com/validate.html. (it's by no means the best around)